# mostrar una vista segun valor de rol en laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy intentando mostrar una vista u otra dependiendo de/los roles que tenga un determinado usuario, por ejemplo: el usuario con model_id=3' tiene asignados los role_id 1,2 (esto en latabla model_has_roles, por lo cual en mi controlador tengo una funcion que recibe el id del usuario de esta forma:

```
public function createPerfil($id){

        $roles = User::find($id)->roles()->get();

        $empresas = Empresa::all();
        $servicios = Servicio::all();

        echo json_encode($roles);

       // return view ('admin.users.perfil',compact('users', 'empresas','servicios'));
    }
```

pero necesito que segun el role_id me lleve a una vista u otra, intente con un for pero no se bien como traer el role_id a dicha condicion:

```
if ($roles != '3') {
            echo alert('deberia mostrar el formulario de funcionarios');
        }
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Nos explicarías que tipo de relación existe entre usuarios y roles?

Comment: Hola @BetaM seria una relacion 1:M (un usuario tiene un rol y un rol puede pertencer a uno o mas usuarios), estoy trabajando con laravel permissions

Comment: Y por que no empleas los métodos que ese paquete ya tiene definidos para esas situaciones?